# Java Thread Programming example - programs is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading **Java Thread Programming** a book by **Paul Hyde**.I am into intial chapter. I am running various sample programs in Eclipse IDE.

```
public class TwoThreadAlive extends Thread {
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printMsg();
    }
}

public void printMsg() {
    // get a reference to the thread running this
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    String name = t.getName();
    System.out.println("name=" + name);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoThreadAlive tt = new TwoThreadAlive();
    tt.setName("my worker thread");

    System.out.println("before start(), tt.isAlive()=" + tt.isAlive());
    tt.start();
    System.out.println("just after start(),tt.isAlive()=" + tt.isAlive());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tt.printMsg();
    }

    System.out
            .println("at the end of main(), tt.isAlive()=" + tt.isAlive());
}}
```

This program is giving **SAME** output every time I run it.But it has mentioned that output will differ as JVM will be busy in context switching.Can you please tell me that why it is giving same output?

And it is giving

```
at the end of main(), tt.isAlive()=true
```

This should have been

```
at the end of main(), tt.isAlive()=false
```

Please help me , this is making me mad.

Comment: can you print the output that you are getting...

Comment: Try increasing the number of iterations in the for-loops. Perhaps there is just too little work and no context switching is performed.

Comment: increase the loop inside main method to a higher value. You should be able to simulate that. The way in which your current program outputs need not be the same on other machines, scheduling threads is left to the OS and other parameters at the the time you are running the program.

Comment: It worked for i=10000 inside main method loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, the output is correct because by the time the `main` method executes the last `println` there is no guarantee that also your thread has finished executing. Add a `tt.join();` right before the last print:

```
tt.join();

System.out
        .println("at the end of main(), tt.isAlive()=" + tt.isAlive());
```

Now the main thread will be blocked until `tt` finishes, and so the `println` will execute only after `tt` is dead.

As for your output being always the same, 10 is a too fine grain value and most likely each thread finishes printing everything by the time it gets context switched. Try with a much larger value.

Comment: that means smaller value will tend to give same output every time I run it, then why the writer mention the small values while giving an example.Its confusing.

Comment: @Suman_Sohal: Do you have a multi-core or single core machine? On a multi-core it's more likely to happen because the threads truly execute in parallel, while on a single core they don't. It's also possible that simply the writer did not bother to actually test what he wrote, but from my experience only 10 iterations will (probably) never show you interleaved output.

Comment: I have 64-bit Intel Xeon W3503.It has 2 cores.

Comment: thats seems correct....but what if I change the java.exe and javaw.exe affinity to single CPU in task manager and restart the service.Will that make any difference.I tried, but it is giving same output.

Comment: @Suman_Sohal, well there are many factors here to take into account, like the lock on the console, which cannot be updated simultaneously by two threads, the buffers to store the data written to the output, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not really <strike>clean</strike> readable code, I think the `printMsg()` should be static and maybe be placed inside the main class. That way you'll be able to notice that its behavior is not dependent on the custom thread class. Since it prints the current thread name, you could see (for a higher number of iterations) the JVM switching between your `TwoThreadAlive` thread and the main thread.
About the `isAlive` question, the `TwoThreadAlive` thread may not have finished its execution when the main finishes. Change the main thread iterations to 100 and the custom thread to 10000 to see this effect.